# Retrieving User Input using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service

I am using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript to build a web application. Within the web app a geoprocessing service is executed which requires an input that is user dependent.

I thought of a text box where the user can enter a value, which should then be read by the application and used for the geoprocessing service.

How can this be done? 
I searched on the ArcGIS API website and in the Internet, but I could not find any solution so far.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily with some HTML by using a text box somewhere in your page or in a modal window:

`<input type="text" id="out-folder">`

And then for the params of your GP Service in JavaScript:

```
// set up params
var gpParams = {
    "Boundary": fs,
    "Layer_URL": dom.byId("layer-choice").value,
    "Output_Folder_Name": dom.byId("out-folder").value,  //var from text box is here
    "Include_Features": dom.byId("include-features").checked
}
```

In my example, I'm using the [dojo.dom](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom.html) to get the textbox value, but you can also do this with standard JavaScript like this:

`document.getElementById("out-folder").value`

I have some very basic examples of using GP services with the JavaScript API [here](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/2015_MN_GIS_GP_SERVICES_JSAPI).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It should have been accepted. The presentation is really nice!